# Solve a system of slope-intercept, ODE, and PDE with spatial and time variable

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica and I need to solve a system of coupled ODE and PDE with two variables (space and time) and one of the parameters is only dependent on the space.
The set of partial differential equation in y(z,t) and q(z,t) to solve are Eq 1 and Eq 2
[image]
wf is only dependent on the space and constant with respect to time.
[image]
[image]

The code I have written is as follows:

```
ClearAll[y, q, wf]
\[Gamma] = Cd/4 Pi St; c = 3; M = 
 CL0/16 Pi^2 St^2 \[Mu]; \[Epsilon] = 0.3; A = 12; St = 0.16; Cd = \
1.2; CL0 = 0.3; \[Mu] = 1.785 ; \[CapitalLambda] = 100;
System = {
   wf[z, t] == 2*z + 10,
   D[y[z, t], t, t] + (\[Gamma] wf[z, t]/\[Mu])*D[y[z, t], t] - 
     c^2*D[y[z, t], z, z] == wf[z, t]^2 M q[z, t],
   D[q[z, t], t, t] + \[Epsilon]*wf[z, t]*(q[z, t]^2 - 1)*
      D[q[z, t], t] + q[z, t]*wf[z, t]^2 == A D[y[z, t], t, t],
   y[0, t] == 0 ,
   y[\[CapitalLambda], t] == 0,
   q[z, 0] == 10^-3,
   y[z, 0] == 0,
   D[y[z, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0,
   D[y[z, t], z] == 0 /. z -> 0,
   D[q[z, t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0
   
   };
{y, q, wf} = 
 NDSolveValue[
  System, {y, q, wf}, {z, 0, \[CapitalLambda]}, {t, 0, 800}]
Plot3D[{y[z, t], q[z, t]}, {z, 0, \[CapitalLambda]}, {t, 0, 800}]
```

PS: When Wf is set to 1 (as constant) the code ran fine. But with a spatial variable parameter it doesn't.

Comment: Do not treat `wf` as a dependent variable.  Instead, remove it from `NDSolveValue` and `System` and define it as a function prior to the definition of `System`: `wf[z_, t_] := 2*z + 10`.  Unfortunately, the solution looks numerically unstable, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you it working now, I have another question, since the computation is heavy, I would like to set steps to increment t by 0.01 and z by 0.1. How do I do that ?

Comment: The cell size in `z` defaults to about `4` here.  reducing it to `0.1` will increase the run time by at least a factor of `40`.  In general, allowing `NDSolve` to choose its own variable time step is most efficient.  However, if your code is numerically unstable, the time step is likely to be very small.  Run the code to, say, `t = 20` and check whether the plot seems reasonable.

Comment: Is there a way to export data in a table from this particular code? The values of y[z,t] for example